# Use for loop to get distinct value each column of a data frame with count of the distinct value

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is the example if a table :-

Table

```
A      B    Income
satya India 10000
Amlan Usa   20000
Satya India 10000
Amlan Usa   20000
Sid   India 30000
```

**Results required**

Query 1

```
A <- sqldf( " Select distinct A,sum(Income) from Table ")

A     Total
Satya 20000
Amlan 40000
Sid   30000
```

Query 2

```
B <- sqldf( " Select distinct B,Sum(Income) from Table ")

B     Total 
India 50000
Usa   40000
```

I want use a loop so that I can write one query and get unique value of each filed with sum of income, instead of writing separate query for each field .I want this in R.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
df <- data.frame(A = c('satya', 'Amlan', 'Satya', 'Amlan', 'Sid'), 
             B = c('India', 'Usa', 'India', 'Usa', 'India'), 
             Income = c(10000, 20000, 10000, 20000, 30000))

# Converting to upper case since R is case sensitive
df$A <- toupper(df$A)
df$B <- toupper(df$B)

Cols_Group <- names(df)[!names(df) %in% 'Income']

library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# Creating different objects for each column
for(i in Cols_Group) {
  assign(i, df[, .(Total = sum(Income)), i])
}

A

       A Total
1: SATYA 20000
2: AMLAN 40000
3:   SID 30000

B

       B Total
1: INDIA 50000
2:   USA 40000
```

If you need it in single object you may use the below code

```
Result <- data.table()

for(i in Cols_Group) {
  Result <- rbindlist(list(Result, df[, .(Total = sum(Income)), i]), use.names = FALSE)
}

Result

       A Total
1: SATYA 20000
2: AMLAN 40000
3:   SID 30000
4: INDIA 50000
5:   USA 40000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

First of all, you need to loop through the `colnames` in the for loop and inside `sqldf` statement, you need to pass that `colname` using `sprintf' Otherwise, it won't work.

```
col_names <- colnames(df)
col_names <- col_names[-length(col_names)]

for (i in col_names) {
  A <- sqldf(sprintf( "Select distinct %s, sum(Income) as Total from df group by %s", i, i))
  print(A)
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
      A Total
1 Amlan 40000
2 Satya 20000
3   Sid 30000
      B Total
1 India 50000
2    US 40000
```

Hereafter, you can append the results to a list or create a data frame as you wish.

**EDIT: To save df to different Excel files**

In order to save the `df` to a new excel file every time, you'll need to use a package called `xlsx`.

Your code will look like this:

```
for (i in col_names) {
  A <- sqldf(sprintf( "Select distinct %s, sum(Income) as Total from df group by %s", i, i))
  write.xlsx(A, file = paste0(i, '.xlsx'))
}
```

Note: It will save the `df` in an excel file with the name of the column. (look for `i` in the `write.xlsx` function.

Comment: Thank you all for the information

Comment: Hi Vishal A Instead of Print I want these details in a table ?

Comment: It's already a `data.frame`. What else you want?

Comment: If you want, to use is as a `tibble` though, you can use library `tidyverse` and change the print statement to `print(as_tibble(A))`.

Comment: If it helps, you can accept the answer by clicking the tick button. It motivates me to help other people on the platform.

Comment: I want to use a loop to extract the table to Excel and for each table I have write the code time
write.xlsx(A,"A.xlsx") write.xlsx(B,"B.xlsx")

Comment: @SatyajeetSingh, I've updated the code to save the results in an excel file. Please accept it as an answer. I see the other answer accepted as an answer.